# Django annotate() error AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'

Tags: python, django

Hello I want to concatenate more fields into django, but even this simple code:

```
    Project.objects.annotate(
        companyname=Concat('company__name',Value('ahoj')),output_field=CharField()    
    )
```

Gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'
```

Traceback:

```
  File "/root/MUP/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 122, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/MUP/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 908, in annotate
    clone.query.add_annotation(annotation, alias, is_summary=False)
  File "/root/MUP/djangoenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 986, in add_annotation
    annotation = annotation.resolve_expression(self, allow_joins=True, reuse=None,
AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have a closing parenthesis in the wrong place. The `output_field` is an argument for `Concat`, not for `annotate`. It should be:

```
Project.objects.annotate(
    companyname=Concat('company__name', Value('ahoj'), output_field=CharField()),    
)
```

Comment: Oh shit. Thanks. They have a really bad example with the parentheses in the documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/database-functions/#concat
`.annotate(screen_name=Concat('name', V(' ('), 'goes_by', V(')'), output_field=CharField()))`

Comment: Yes, I agree that example in the docs is tricky to read. If you opened a pull request to change the formatting I'm pretty sure it would be accepted.